# Pandasql hangs when used with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pandasql

Using pandasql with multiprocessing ends up hanging some of the time (namely when many processes are used concurrently).

The matching function works fine on a single set of input data (not using multiprocessing). The multiprocessing code works fine with other functions. When the matching function is used with multiprocessing, one or more processes tend to hang. I've also tried changing the multiprocessing context to "spawn" to avoid potential copying of locks from the parent process, but that didn't help.

```
def matching(inputData):
    q = """
        SELECT
            df1.time,
            df2.time,
            df1.lat,
            df2.lat,
            df1.lng,
            df2.lng,
            (JulianDay(df2.time) - JulianDay(df1.time)) * 24 * 60  as timeDiff
        FROM 
            df1
        LEFT JOIN
            df2
        WHERE
            timeDiff < 5 AND 
            timeDiff >= -2 AND
            ABS(df1.lat - df2.lat) < .02 AND
            ABS(df1.lng - df2.lng) < .02;
    """
    currentDate, df1, df2 = inputData
    result = pandasql.sqldf(q, locals())
    return result

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
df = pandas.concat(pool.map(matching, matchingData))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The input data, matchingData, is a list of tuples containing data set pairs. Each data set pair corresponds to a single date. The matching code should split the file pairs across 16 processes at a time. The result should be a Pandas dataframe containing the merged data for all dates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to stem from the pandasql package using the sqlalchemy package with SQLite in each process. To mimic what pandasql is doing using the sqlalchemy package, I wrote the below code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sqlalchemy

def testing(iteration):
    print("Started for iteration {}".format(iteration))

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite://', 
                                  echo = True)

    print("Created engine for iteration {}".format(iteration))

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        print("Established database connection for iteration {}".format(iteration))

pool = mp.Pool(2)
results = pool.map(testing, range(2))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Sqlalchemy successfully creates both engines, but only creates a connection for one of the two engines. The problem can be fixed by using sqlalchemy with MySQL instead of SQLite. Because pandasql uses SQLite, it should not be used with multiprocessing.